# Кодировка в файле Базы данных Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

Имею следующий код(кривоватый, но пока что хочу разобраться с проблемой):

```
        string connection = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=[путь к файлу mdf];Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connection);
        sqlConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT Наименование, Тип
                                                 FROM Bluda;", sqlConnection);
        SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (sqlDataReader.Read())
        {
            if (DataWorker.ConvertToString(sqlDataReader["Тип"]) == "1")
            {
                string adder = DataWorker.ConvertToString(sqlDataReader["Наименование"]) + '\n';
                this.Data1.Text += adder;
            }
            else if (DataWorker.ConvertToString(sqlDataReader["Тип"]) == "2")
            {
                string adder = DataWorker.ConvertToString(sqlDataReader["Наименование"]) + '\n';
                this.Data2.Text += adder;
            }
            else if (DataWorker.ConvertToString(sqlDataReader["Тип"]) == "3")
            {
                string adder = DataWorker.ConvertToString(sqlDataReader["Наименование"]) + '\n';
                this.Data3.Text += adder;
            }
        }
```

По сути, работает правильно, да вот только кодировка мешает(как всегда, кириллица страдает). Высматривал решение проблемы на других форумах, там нужно было, по словам прохфессионалов, заменить тип данных в базе с char на nvarchar, что я и сделал. Однако это тоже не помогло.

Comment: А почему не сделать запрос к БД с фильтрацией по типу: `SELECT Наименование, Тип FROM Bluda WHERE Тип = 1`? А потом для типа 2 и т.д. Сервер надо нагружать работой, а не приложение. Когда базу создавали надо было указать `COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS` чтоб с кириллицей работа была нормальной.

Comment: После создания базы каким запросом кодировку поставить? Тем более я написал, что код кривоват, потом все равно менять буду.

Comment: `ALTER DATABASE ВашаБаза
COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS
GO`

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 'go'

Comment: Уберите GO тогда

Comment: Убрал. Оно хочет чтобы я что-то бесконечно туда вводил. Какой-то ввод нужен.

Comment: Я проверял команду на рабочей базе в Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio у меня все работало. Значит кривенько вводите команду или запускаете ее. Закройте команду не Go а точкой с запятой.

Comment: а имеет значение, использую ли я именно сервер или файл базы данных mdf?

Comment: Нет не имеет....